How to Include Windows Service Bin Files in MAUI MSIX Package
I have a MAUI project and a Windows service project in my solution. I would like my published MAUI MSIX to include all output bin files from my Windows service project. Below is the relevant section of my MAUI .csproj file:
...

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\QC.WindowService\QuadonClient.WindowService.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="CopyWindowsServiceFiles" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ServiceProjectFiles Include="..\QC.WindowService\bin\$(Configuration)\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ServiceProjectFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\QCService" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />

    <!-- Conditionally copy to $(OutputPath)\AppX\QCService if AppX exists -->
    <PropertyGroup>
        <AppXOutputPath Condition="Exists('$(OutputPath)\AppX')">$(OutputPath)\AppX\QCService</AppXOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ServiceProjectFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(AppXOutputPath)" Condition="Exists('$(OutputPath)\AppX')" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>

<Target Name="PublishWindowsServiceFiles" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <ItemGroup>
        <PublishExtraFiles Include="..\QC.WindowService\bin\$(Configuration)\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(PublishExtraFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)\QCService\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>

...

I run the following command to publish:
dotnet publish -f net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -c Release -p:RuntimeIdentifierOverride=win10-x64

The output bin files from my Windows service project are correctly copied to my release output directory and the publish folder. However, when I check the AppPackages folder, my MSIX does not contain the Windows service files. Why is this happening? I assumed the MSIX would be packed based on the publish folder. Is there anything I need to change to ensure the Windows service files are included in the MSIX?
